# Run/debug node.js testcases with jasmine in Webstorm 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm

I install Webstorm 11 and want to run my tests (for node.js app) implemented with Jasmine.
However it's not easy to do that. I could just type in command line 'jasmine' command and test will be runned, but in this case I'm not able to debug code.
So is there a way to configure Webstorm to deal with jasmine specs as it should?

Comment: Why not https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/enabling-javascript-unit-testing-support.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so while no one answer at the moment I will try to provide my version:
This flow will allow to run jasmine testsute from Webstrom and debug testcases

1. install jasmine (ither locally or globally)
2. in project folder create folder 'spec/support' In this folder place jasmine.json

   tests configuration example:

   ```
   {
   "spec_dir": "tests",
   "spec_files": [
       "**/*[sS]pec.js"
   ],
   "helpers": [
       "helpers/**/*.js"
   ]
   }
   ```
3. Create node.js configuration in Webstorm
4. In this configuration select source file - jasmine executable file (for localy installed
   jasmine it will be `'node_modules\jasmine\bin\jasmine.js'` )

So you are ready. However at the current moment when trying to debug this configuration - it fails with error:

`Cannot stop on breakpoint due to internal error org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor$1:`

If you faced with it - you need to change Webstom configuration and set this settings:

`-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false` For more details check [there:](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139990)

So this allow you to run jasmine tests and debug them. However there is still some things which this solution not able to do:

1. Run individual testcases
2. Run individual testcases with right click button and Run command from menu

---

Jetbrains, if you reading this - please fix this already. I started play with node in Webstorm 3 years ago and since that moment and dozens of version there is still no nice way to run tests. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine works with the JSTestDriver which you get out-of-the-box with WebStorm 11:
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/enabling-javascript-unit-testing-support.html

This page also details how to add Jasmine within JSTestDriver:
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/preparing-to-use-jstestdriver-test-runner.html

At a high level you're going to:

1. Install JSTestDriver from JetBrains plugin repo
2. Configure it as a WebStorm JavaScript library (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#configure)
3. Open jsTestDriver.conf and type the following code in it:

load:

lib/jasmine/jasmine.js

lib/jasmine-jstd-adapter/JasmineAdapter.js

Comment: JsTestDriver not shipped with Webstrom by default, you will need to install additional plugin to use it. However it's looks like JsTestDriver itself is abandoned project who not longer maintains at all (looks like last release was 3-4 years ago) and it's not clear does it support node.js or it's only for clientside js. So with all this questions I think it's not an option.

Comment: Have a look @ the Karma docs then, this supports Jasime also: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/preparing-to-use-karma-test-runner.html

Comment: Once again, karma - is a clientside js tests runner. It's good for angular, but not working for node.js

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm doesn't manage test running directly. This job is done by a test runner. WebStorm supports several test runners - Mocha, Karma, JsTestDriver, nodeunit. Most of them can execute Jasmine tests

Comment: I think you are wrong. But maybe not. Could you provide me with algorithm - how I could run NODE.JS jasmine base testcases with mocha or nodeunit (only they could run server side js tests, karma and JsTestDriver work only for client). I don't want anything extraordinary - just want to click righ mouse button and run single testcase. Should be easy for "most intelligent javascript IDE in the world", right?